# Webassembly compiler code executed with an error

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to implement (encoding only) in WebAssembly, the goal is to have a very light weight wasm module. As a web developer my C knowledge is limited. For now I've implemented the following function to encode.

```html
fetch('/js/test.wasm').then(response =>
      response.arrayBuffer()
    ).then(bytes =>
      WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, imports)
    ).then(results => {
      /* console.log(results.instance.exports.findHash(
        '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 35, 0, 35, 4, 'deecf819-611c-4f46-b150-347190abcd31', 'e7e78d72acfc6e7d727bd9112c8ff64704cfb0a73a738799119acc8bdaa6a6d3e9788de4614a27c349d8e80b6d55cb1d63223f528175fb9247ba8e85ba59dfca'
      )); */
      console.log(results);
    });
```

Comment: Don't use a bare WebAssembly compiler. Use Emscripten (emcc) for C. Also I don't think running a crypto in a browser is a good idea..

Comment: emcc start.c -o test.wasm  (did not help), 


Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="wasi_snapshot_preview1" error: module is not an object or function

Comment: No, you should output test.js, not test.wasm. Then stop using your js fetch code. Also consider using -s MODULARIZE=1 -s EXPORT_ES6=1

Comment: How to use functions findHash?